# 没有 as an answer. Cannot be 不?。

Tags: grammar

I have been studying a simple dialog that says:

A> 你家住在哪里? 还住在城里?
The answer was.
B> 没有。我们最近搬到郊外住了。

If A was asking about the present how can you answer with 没有.besides the question does not have the verb 有。

My answer would be, 我们不住在城里。我们最经搬到郊外。

Is the dialog correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question that was asked:

A> 你家住在哪里? 还住在城里? The answer was. B> 没有。我们最近搬到郊外住了。

The response provided here (没有) is emphasizing the second part of the question 还住在城里? regarding whether you still live in the city (i.e. not anymore, we recently moved to the outer suburbs). Since 还 indicates a state, the response 没有 tells you that the state does not exist anymore so it makes sense.

Your response of 我们不住在城里。我们最经搬到郊外。has a slightly different meaning, which could suggest that the person asking the question was incorrect about you ever having lived in the city, and that you have moved recently to the outer suburbs.

I should also point out that there appears to be a typo for the phrase 我们最经搬到郊外, I think you meant 最近 and not 最经.

Answer (score 3):

> A:你家住在哪里? 还住在城里?

Both 没有 and 不 denote negative, B is replying to latter part of the  question "还住在城里嗎?" B's reply would either be positive or negative. And he doesn't need to repeat A's question in his answer, so he could simply answer:

"不"(meaning 不是住在城里)

or

"没有" (meaning 没有住在城里)

"我们最近搬到郊外住了" is not a part of the answer but an additional explanation

Notice "还住在城里嗎?" is a question asking for confirmation of positive or negative, so you can simply reply with a negative "不/ 不是 /没有", or a positive "是"

However, if the question is specifically asking "是不是" or "有没有', you have to answer specifically with "是/ 不是" or "有/ 没有"

Example:

A: "有沒有工作?"

B: "有" (you cannot reply with "是")

B: "沒有" (you cannot reply with "不是")

~

A: "是不是你?"

B: "是" (you cannot reply with "有")

B: "不是" (you cannot reply with "沒有")

Also: reply with the verb used in the question

A: 去不去玩?

B: 去 (you cannot reply with "有去")

B: 不/ 不去 (you cannot reply with "沒/ 沒去")

Answer (score 2):

To answer you question, the dialog is correct.

没有 can be used colloquially to just mean negative.